# Functional Equation and Definite Integral Combo

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, functional-equations

> Given that a function $f(x)$ satisfies $$f(x)+2 f\left(\frac{2 x-1}{x+1}\right)=\frac{x}{(x+1)\left(x^2+4\right)}$$ Then find $$\int_3^4 f\left(\frac{x-2}{2 x-1}\right) d x$$

**My hard effort**:
Let $$h(x)=\frac{x}{(x+1)\left(x^2+4\right)}$$
The given functional equation is:
$$f(x)+2 f\left(\frac{2 x-1}{x+1}\right)=h(x)$$
Replace $x$ with $\frac{2x-1}{x+1}$ above, then we get
$$\boxed{f\left(\frac{2 x-1}{x+1}\right)+2 f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=h\left(\frac{2 x-1}{x+1}\right)}----(1)$$

Also from the functional equation, replace $x$ with $x+1$, we get
$$\boxed{f(x+1)+2 f\left(\frac{2 x+1}{x+2}\right)=h(x+1)}----(2)$$

Now comes the interesting part:
Let us assume
$$I=\int_3^4 f\left(\frac{x-2}{2 x-1}\right) d x---(3)$$
Use the substitution $x=\frac{-1}{v}$, then we get
$$\boxed{I=\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{-1}{4}} \frac{f\left(\frac{2 v+1}{v+2}\right)}{v^2} d v }----(4)$$
Also in the integral $(3)$, use the substitution $x=\frac{-1}{u-1}$, we get
$$\boxed{I=\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \frac{f\left(\frac{2 u-1}{u+1}\right)}{(u-1)^2} d u}-----(5)$$
Now divide equation $(1)$ through out by $(x-1)^2$ and Integrate from the limits $\frac{2}{3} \to \frac{3}{4}$, we get
$$\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \frac{f\left(\frac{2 x-1}{x+1}\right)}{(x-1)^2} d x+2 \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \frac{f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}{(x-1)^2} d x=\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \frac{h\left(\frac{2 x-1}{x+1}\right)}{(x-1)^2} d x$$
$$\implies I+2J=\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \frac{h\left(\frac{2 x-1}{x+1}\right)}{(x-1)^2} d x------(6)$$
Also divide equation $(2)$ through out by $x^2$ and integrate from limits $\frac{-1}{3}\to \frac{-1}{4}$,then we get
$$\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{-1}{4}} \frac{f(x+1)}{x^2} d x+2 \int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{-1}{4}} \frac{f\left(\frac{2 x+1}{x+2}\right)}{x^2} d x=\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{-1}{4}} \frac{h(x+1)}{x^2} d x$$
$$\Rightarrow K+2I=\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{-1}{4}} \frac{h(x+1)}{x^2} d x----(7)$$
Where $$J=\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \frac{f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}{(x-1)^2} d x,\:K=\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{-1}{4}} \frac{f(x+1)}{x^2} d x$$

Any inputs please?

Comment: Keep making the substitution you made in (1). I think on the 5th iteration, it will circle back and you will have something useful.

Comment: Also, since there's no other assumption on $f$'s regularity/behaviour, you might want to justify that the integral in question actually exists, I think? Though it'll probably come along during the proof anyway. With such types of equations you kinda have to be careful since there might be discontinuous solutions.